# What kind of points are left in the set with rationals subtracted, who contains all rationals and is null?

Tags: nt.number-theory, set-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let {$q_i$} be a list of all rationals, $U_{i,n}$ be an open interval centered at $q_i$ with length of $2^{-i}/n$. Then open set $\bigcup_{i}U_{i,n} $ has the length of $1/n$ and contains all rationals. The $G_{\delta}$ set $G$ $=$ $\bigcap_n\bigcup_i U_{i,n}$ has measure 0.

From above, we know that $G-\Bbb{Q}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ null set and contains only irrationals. We can also prove that it's dense:

> The countable intersection of the open sets $\{q\}^c$ where $c$ means complement forms a $G_{\delta}$ set (let's name it $D$) containing exactly all irrationals. Take $D\bigcup G$ and use the Baire category theorem, we know that it's dense. Hence $G-\Bbb{Q}$ is dense.

Then what kind of points are in $G-\Bbb{Q}$? Can we give them some representations or descriptions? If they are written out in decimal, are there any patterns?

Comment: For the issues you are interested in I suspect the ordering of the list of rationals is relevant, so a better question might be to ask about descriptions and patterns that are independent of the ordering of the list. And while focusing on decimal expansions (rather than $n$-ary expansions for other values of $n,$ continued fraction expansions, and other representations of real numbers) and the specific "powers of $\frac{1}{2}$" interval lengths, it's probably best to start with something specific such as you've described. And this is probably more number-theoretic than suggested by your tags.

Comment: To build off of @DaveLRenfro's comment, *any* irrational $r$ can be omitted from this process if we choose our ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$ appropriately. (I think this would better fit MSE, incidentally.)

Comment: I notice that some of my comment seems a bit too close to being a [word salad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_salad) than I thought I had written. Maybe this will clarify my second sentence: While it is easy to generalize and ask about $n$-ary expansions, continued fraction expansions, and other things (e.g. changing the sequence of interval lengths), when beginning to look at this issue, it's probably best to keep things fairly specific, and only consider tweaking to something else if you happen to notice that something nontrivial can be deduced when a tweak to something else is made.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Structure_of_the_set_of_Liouville_numbers for a construction similar to this, where the numbers remaining are called "Liouvlle numbers".